# Recurly returning validation error

Tags: php, recurly

I'm trying to use the Recurly php client library to integrate the service into a PHP platform and I'm running into an error that doesn't seem to make sense.

I've created a form as described [here](https://dev.recurly.com/docs/getting-a-token) which gets a token that submits it to my code below to create the actual account and subscription. In my controller, I have the below code:

```
protected function _actionAdd($context)
{
    $viewer = get_viewer();
    $plan = $this->getService('repos:subscriptions.plan')->fetch($context->data->get('plan'));

    try {
        $recurlySubscription = new Recurly_Subscription();
        $recurlySubscription->plan_code = $plan->code; // "test-plan"

        $recurlySubscription->account = new Recurly_Account();
        $recurlySubscription->account->account_code = $viewer->id;
        $recurlySubscription->account->first_name = $context->data->get('first_name');
        $recurlySubscription->account->last_name = $context->data->get('last_name');
        $recurlySubscription->account->email = $viewer->email;

        $recurlySubscription->account->billing_info = new Recurly_BillingInfo();
        $recurlySubscription->account->billing_info->token_id = $context->data->get('recurly-token');

        $recurlySubscription->create();

    } catch( Recurly_ValidationError $e) {
        print "Invalid Account: $e";
    }


}
```

Most of the above code is from the provided example [here](https://dev.recurly.com/docs/using-a-token). The form includes the plan id in the `plan` property which I then look up the plan code from my own database along with the current user's information.

For some reason, I'm getting the following error:

```
Invalid Account: exception 'Recurly_ValidationError' with message 'Currency is not included in the list, currency not accepted by site, unit amount in cents is not a number.'
```

I've looked over `test-plan` and my site settings numerous times. Both are  set to USD as the default currency and I have no idea why `unit amount in cents` would matter since I'm not even dealing with it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, you're expected to include the currency of the subscription even though it's not specified in the example. Including the below fixes the issue.

```
$recurlySubscription->currency = 'USD';
```